# How to fully recreate database in MS SQL server 2016 from exported data

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

Recently I get many consistency errors very often in my ~40Gb database. Of course I use `DBCC CHECKDB`, even with `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` (when it asks), but then again I get errors, even after read-only operations.

Database itself is stored on SSD drive which is ok, so I suspect there are some hidden errors in database file.

So, the full cycle: I have MSSQL 2016 on local PC, with only 1 user attached. Every day I get data (~1.5M records) in custom format, backup base and insert data to the base (non-bulk inserts, indexes on). During that operation no one touches the base. Later from time to time I make high load queries (different statistics). And often I get consistency errors, check sum errors, index errors (don't have exact output stored in the moment). Index errors can be corrected by rebuilding indexes; others can only be fixed with `DBCC CHECKDB` using the `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` option. After that, it works again - for a little while.

I don't believe the problem is with my SSD drive. I have tried different drives on this PC over the past few years, with no change in behavior.

I suspect that, even after running `DBCC CHECKDB` successfully, there are some hidden errors in file structure which lead to new errors later. So I want extract only the data to linear file and then import it. Standard Export wizard exports hundreds of lines and then stopped without error.

Is there a correct and robust way to export the whole DB to text/binary file(s) (but not mssql) and then recreate database without data losses from those file(s)? I tried backup-restore, but it looks like database consistency problems persist through restoration.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66263/discussion-on-question-by-tertium-how-to-fully-recreate-database-in-ms-sql-serve).

Answer (score 6):

> This is only a summary of some vague assumptions as a lot of details that should be added to the question were either discussed in a [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66263/discussion-on-question-by-tertium-how-to-fully-recreate-database-in-ms-sql-serve) or have not yet been asked.

** Before you continue**

Create a database backup (`WITH CHECKSUM`) and store this database in a safe location. Even better: Seeing as your disk might be faulty, backup the database (`WITH CHECKSUM`) to an external drive and store in a safe location.

Possible reasons for data corruption on data growth

---

1. Your SSD disk has corrupt areas. `DBCC CHECKDB...` corrects the data (albeit with `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`). Adding data places it in the corrupt areas of the SSD even though the SSD controller unit should avoid corrupt areas (once marked).

**Solution:** Check SSD S.M.A.R.T. parameters for errors and/or replace SSD.

***Reference:*** [How to See If Your Hard Drive Is Dying with S.M.A.R.T.](https://www.howtogeek.com/134735/how-to-see-if-your-hard-drive-is-dying/) (How-To Geek Site)

---

2. Your motherboard's disk controller (SATA interface) is having issues handling the large amount of data.

**Solution:** Replace disk controller and/or update disk controller driver.

---

3. The disk and/or disk controller is set to use a WRITE CACHE mechanism which is unable to keep up with the import of large amounts of data. The corruption is occurring on flushing.

**Solution:** Turn off (disk) cache mechanisms.

***Reference:*** [Disable Windows Disk Write Cache for Data Integrity and Better Performance](http://longwhiteclouds.com/2017/01/05/disable-windows-disk-write-cache-for-data-integrity-and-better-performance/) (Long White Virtual Clouds)

---

***General Reference:*** [Data corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_corruption) (Wikipedia)

Comment: Currently I've found several errors in memory module, replaced them all. Disks are ok, however I disabled caching. Don't know about motherboard, assume it does work and will see in the nearest future.